# Android - extract one channel from stereo .mp3, apply it through both channels of an AudioStream

Tags: android, audio, mp3, audio-streaming, android-music-player

I'm trying to load an .mp3 file, and distinguish between the left and right channels. I would like to copy the data from the left channel and create an AudioStream that plays the data from the left channel through both the left and the right channels.

I've been trying to implement it using this code, but it seems to produce an indecipherable array of bytes

```
    InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.flume);

    soundBytes1 = new byte[inputStream.available()];
    soundBytes1 = toByteArray(inputStream);



    public byte[] toByteArray(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int read = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (read != -1) {
        read = in.read(buffer);
        if (read != -1)
            out.write(buffer,0,read);
    }
    out.close();
    return out.toByteArray();
}
```

I would prefer to be able to perform this process with any .mp3 file. Is it necessary for the audio to be converted to some other format in order for the channels to be distinguished?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it necessary for the audio to be converted to some other format in order for the channels to be distinguished?

Yes.  MP3, like most lossy formats, combines the audio channels together (in most cases) and effectively stores differences between them.  This saves significant bandwidth as the left and right tracks are usually very similar.  Saving this bandwidth increases the overall quality for a given bitrate.

Therefore, you can't just read a frame for one channel, and then read a frame for the next channel.  You must decode the MP3 audio back to PCM first.